# MediaRecorder is not recording in some phones

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, mediarecorder

In few specific mobile phones like Lenovo K6 Power(K33A42) mediarecorder is not recording, I've tried changing all AudioSource, On VOICE_CALL it doesn't record. On the MIC it records but the output file is silent.

```
 private void startRecording() {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: its not recording in few specific phones.

Comment: so, did you try using different output format?

Comment: yeah, tried all,  But did'nt work.

Comment: please be more specific, "didn't work" could mean a lot of things. are you getting an empty output file? is the duration of the file correct but is silent? are you getting any error in the log?

Comment: i apologize for that. i'm getting an output file, duration of the file is  correct but its silent .

Comment: no need to apologies, the thing is, the more details and info you give, the higher is the probability to spot the problem

Comment: I find it unclear exactly _what_ you're trying to record. You mention the `VOICE_CALL` audio source, so I'm _guessing_ that you want to record both the downlink and uplink audio of voice calls, but you never state explicitly what the use case is.

Comment: maybe the mic was being used (locked) by another app?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have used:

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1); //you can set it to 2 if you want stereo
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFilePath(starttime));
```

I haven't had any problems with this setup so far. Alternatively you can try to combine [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) and [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html). [This](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments/blob/audioonly/HWEncoderExperiments/src/main/java/net/openwatch/hwencoderexperiments/AudioEncoder.java) example might give you some clue. I haven't tried this particular example but I have been doing something similar in my company's project.

Comment: would you mind elaborate how this answer could solve the problem?

Comment: As far as I can tell media encoding is a mysterious area of Android. It's hard to tel why it doesn't work on one device and why it works on another. I tried Ace's code (which is basically what the Android documentation provides) but I ran into many customer complaints. After a long trial and error period I came across this setup, and it has worked. This is my best scientific approach. Here is a more complex way of achieving this : https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments/blob/audioonly/HWEncoderExperiments/src/main/java/net/openwatch/hwencoderexperiments/AudioEncoder.java

Comment: if your setup works it's a good thing, if one could also understand _why_ it works, it would be much better

Comment: Yes, I wish I could understand it, but this is Android land :)

Comment: @EndreBörcsök bro i tried that already , and it worked same it records audio but there's  no sound in that audio.

Comment: Just added some more to the post above. That's a lower level implementation but it's worth a try.